# Why is the vacuum state $|0\rangle$ invariant under parity?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, vacuum, weak-interaction, parity

I was studying the leptonic pion decay $\pi\rightarrow l\nu_{l}$, and usually the amplitude is computed by
$$\mathcal{M}(\pi\rightarrow l\nu_{l})=-i\frac{G_{F}}{\sqrt{2}}V^{*}_{ud}\langle0|\bar{d}\gamma_{\nu}(1-\gamma^{5})u|\pi(p_{\pi})\rangle\bar{u}(k')\gamma^{\nu}(1-\gamma^{5})v(k).$$
Then one can write
$$\langle0|\bar{d}\gamma_{\mu}u|\pi(p_{\pi})\rangle=const.\times f_{\pi}p^{\mu}_{\pi}$$
and knowing that $P(\bar{d}\gamma^{\mu}u)P^{-1}=-\eta^{\mu}_{\nu}(\bar{d}\gamma^{\nu}u)$
$$\langle0|\bar{d}\gamma^{\mu}u|\pi(p^{0}_{\pi},\stackrel{\rightarrow}{p}_{\pi})\rangle=\langle0|P^{-1}P(\bar{d}\gamma^{\mu}u)P^{-1}P|\pi(p^{0}_{\pi},\stackrel{\rightarrow}{p}_{\pi})\rangle=-\eta^{\mu}_{\nu}\langle0|\bar{d}\gamma^{\mu}u|\pi(p^{0}_{\pi},-\stackrel{\rightarrow}{p}_{\pi})\rangle.$$
I guess that it has been used the property that $P|0\rangle=|0\rangle$, right? Why does it hold? I mean, physically it sounds reasonable but do I have to take it as a postulate?

Comment: How do you define "vacuum" such that this isn't part of the definition?

Comment: As said, it is totally reasonable but is there any mathematical way to see that?

Comment: @Filippo The *explanation* here seem to be that it is an *assumption* (a "reasonable" assumption) that the vacuum is invariant under parity. I will also note that your assertion that vacuum invariance implies $P|0\rangle=|0\rangle$ seems a bit too strong, since your equation will still hold if $P|0\rangle = e^{i\phi}|0\rangle$ for any fixed phase $\phi$. But this shouldn't be a surprise since states that vary only by a fixed phase are physically equivalent.

Comment: What do you mean "mathematical way"? What is your *mathematical definition* of "the vacuum" that you want to derive this from?

Comment: I don't know, I just asked if there was some way to derive that result... this is because I've seen discrete symmetries defined as operators acting on fields, nothing was said about the vacuum. Thank you all btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I guess that it has been used the property that $P|0\rangle=|0\rangle$, right?

The property $P|0\rangle = |0\rangle e^{i\phi}$ for some fixed $\phi$ has been used, since it is assumed here that the vacuum is invariant under parity.

> Why does it hold? I mean, physically it sounds reasonable but do I have to take it as a postulate?

Yes, you have to take it as a postulate that the vacuum is invariant under parity. This does not **have to be** the case for all types of "ground states," but seems like a very reasonably assumption when your ground state is a true "vacuum" state (a state with nothing in it, no particles for example). To explain a little further, since your vacuum has no particles, it seemingly (and reasonably) can't have any momentum. Therefore, the parity operator can't flip the momentum and thereby change the state.